# Can I speed up a large MySQL/MariaDB join through partitioning or merging?

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, partitioning

I'm trying to run the following join query as part of a more complex one on MariaDB 10.1.26.

```
select distinct
    project_commits.project_id,
    date_format(created_at, '%x%v1') as week_commit
    from project_commits
    left join commits
    on project_commits.commit_id = commits.id;
```

Both join fields are indexed. However, the join involves a full scan of `project_commits` and an index lookup on `commits`.  This is corroborated by the output of `EXPLAIN`.

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                 | rows       | Extra           |
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | project_commits | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                | 5417294109 | Using temporary |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | commits         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | ghtorrent.project_commits.commit_id |          1 |                 |
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

The sizes of the two tables are relatively large: `project_commits` contains 5 billion rows and `commits` 847 million rows. Also the server's memory size is relatively small (16GB).  This probably means that index lookups hit the (unfortunately magnetic) disk, and therefore performance takes a heavy hit.  According to the output of [pmonitor](https://github.com/dspinellis/pmonitor/) run on the generated temporary table, the query, which has already run for more than half a day, will take another 373 hours to complete.

```
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/project_commits#P#p0.MYD 6.68% ETA 373:38:11
```

Could I somehow increase the query's performance either by partitioning the tables, so that the join can be performed in memory, or by forcing MySQL to perform a [sort-merge join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join)? As the time involved for running alternative strategies could be many hours, I'd rather have a suggestion, instead of trying things out.

Comment: why are you taking project_commits.project_id instead of commits.project_id?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: `PARTITIONs` will _not_ help.

Comment: Do you really need `LEFT`?  It inhibits starting with the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MariaDB doesn't seem to support sort-merge joins, I ended up exporting the required fields into two sorted files, performing the `JOIN` and `DISTINCT` with the Unix *join* and *uniq* tools, and importing the result back into the database. The operation took fewer than 12 hours to complete. Full details are [here](https://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20180805/).

Answer (score 6):

From the looks of the EXPLAIN plan, you are doing a full table scan on `project_commits`.

From the looks of the query, I surmise there is a one-to-many relationship from `commits` to `project_commits`. The problem I see is that your query is gathering data as many-on-one.

You are also using `LEFT JOIN`.

Your query is saying:

> Show me all `project_commits` that are connected to or orphaned from `commits`

Instead, you might want the query to say:

> Show me all `project_commits` that are connected to `commits`

## SUGGESTION #1 : Flip Table Order

```
EXPLAIN select distinct
    project_commits.project_id,
    date_format(created_at, '%x%v1') as week_commit
    from commits
    left join project_commits
    on commits.id = project_commits.commit_id;
```

## SUGGESTION #2 : Use `INNER JOIN`

```
EXPLAIN select distinct
    project_commits.project_id,
    date_format(created_at, '%x%v1') as week_commit
    from project_commits
    inner join commits
    on project_commits.commit_id = commits.id;
```

## SUGGESTION #3 : Add `created_at` index

If you are already have an index on `created_at` or if you already have a compound index whose first column is `created_at`, skip this suggestion.

```
ALTER TABLE `project_commits` ADD INDEX created_at_ndx (`created_at`);
```

Adding an index will change `EXPLAIN` plan to do an index scan instead of a table scan

## SUGGESTION #4 : Alter the `JOIN` behavior

You could manipulate the style of the join operation by tweeking the optimizer

According to MySQL Documentation on [Block Nested-Loop and Batched Key Access Joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html)

> When BKA is used, the value of join_buffer_size defines how large the batch of keys is in each request to the storage engine. The larger the buffer, the more sequential access will be to the right hand table of a join operation, which can significantly improve performance.
>
> For BKA to be used, the batched_key_access flag of the optimizer_switch system variable must be set to on. BKA uses MRR, so the mrr flag must also be on. Currently, the cost estimation for MRR is too pessimistic. Hence, it is also necessary for mrr_cost_based to be off for BKA to be used.

This same page recommends doing this:

```
mysql> SET optimizer_switch='mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=off,batched_key_access=on';
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Note : I have no idea what to expect from my suggestions. After all, your `LEFT JOIN` is like an iterative Cartesian Join with the potential of make a temp table that is the following

> 4.573 Quintillion rows (5.4 Billion X 0.847 Billion) being looked up

Have fun and let us know what you find

Comment: Thank you for the many suggestions! The relationship is indeed a one-to-many relationship from `commits` to `project_commits`. According to `EXPLAIN` the `inner join` alternative will perform a scan on the smaller `commit` table, so I'm trying that out.

Comment: Unfortunately, after 20 hours of processing no results have come out. I'm terminating the query, because back-of-the envelope calculations tell me that this is a task that could be performed in less than 10 hours.

Answer (score 0):

creating a covering index on table commits and project_commits should enable an index scan in the correct order can be done.

```
ALTER TABLE `commits` ADD INDEX created_at_ndx (`id`, `created_at`); 

ALTER TABLE `project_commits` ADD INDEX commit_id_ndx (`commit_id`, `project_id`);
```

Then you can do

```
select distinct project_id, date_format(created_at, '%x%v1') as week_commit
 from (select 
    project_commits.project_id,
    commits.created_at
    from commits 
    inner join project_commits
    on project_commits.commit_id = commits.id);
```

PLane should now look like this

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys          | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows       | Extra           |
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     |                 | ALL    |                        |         |         |                                       | ...        | Using temporary |
|    2 | DERIVED     | project_commits | index  | commit_id_ndx          | PRIMARY | 8       |                                       | ...        |  Using index    |
|    2 | DERIVED     | commits         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,created_at_ndx | PRIMARY | 4       | db_9_050611.project_commits.commit_id | ...        |                 |
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Other people have also recommended this index.  I will investigate it. Why the nested SELECT?

Comment: its just an assumption but the query optimizer might not be smart enough to know it need to stream created_at field out of the join and might try to execute  date_format before doing the join or pull all collumn from the "commits" table instead of the only 2 we need.

Comment: I tried building the combined index. As I commented on the corresponding Reddit discussion that this index would take more than one hundred hours to build, which is impractical for a one-off query. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/94r6w6/how_i_slashed_a_sql_query_runtime_from_380_hours/e3xushj/